# Create shortcut to website in Chrome (119+)

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, chromium

It can be useful to setup certain websites like "apps" in Win/Mac/Linux, e.g. Gmail, ChatGPT, SO, Github, etc. Some website have the web app manifest JSON set up to allow you to install this from the address bar, for others you have to do this manually.

These shortcuts also allow you to open the website-"app" as a separate window (not tab).

My recent update to Ubuntu 23.10 erased by Chromium, leaving only Chrome, but also erased all my Website shortcuts.

I used to be able to create shorcuts using:

```
hamburger/ epipsis / three-dot menu > More tools > Create shortcut
```

But this is no longer the case, my Chrome version is 119.

How do I create a website shortcut (allowing me to open the website as a separate window) in Chrome 119+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now available (oddly) under:

hamburger / elipsis / three-dot menu > Save and share > Create shortcut

The sub-menu `Save and share` is new in the elipsis menu, it used to be in the address bar. It is place just under the `More tools` (where `Create shortcut` used to be placed).

[image]